# Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'txtContabilidade' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql-update

No MySQL..

Estou querendo fazer UPDATE em um campo de texto, o mesmo tem cerca de 300 caracteres e não permite faze-lo, informado que está muito longo. Já tentei alterando o tipo de campo até para "Longtext", "VARCHAR(1000)" e não permitiu. É alguma limitação nas configurações do MySQL ou algo assim? O que fazer nesta situação?

Comment: Você pode colocar a mensagem de erro completa?

Comment: Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'txtContabilidade' at row 1...
É somente essa a resposta que emite.

Answer (score 2):

Alterar o campo para longtext deveria solucionar o problema, esse erro é disparado quando a quantia de caracteres é maior do que o armazenamento do campo, então os caracteres excedentes são truncados.

O limite do campo varchar é de 255 (0 a 255).

Tente alterar para longtext novamente, lembre de alterar o nome da tabela, CHARACTER SET e o DEFAULT, caso necessário,

```
ALTER TABLE nomeDaTabela CHANGE txtContabilidade txtContabilidade LONGTEXT CHARACTER 
    SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

se não conseguir, envie os códigos relativos ao problema, query insert, query select e a structure da tua tabela, que testarei por aqui e te ajudo a resolver isso.

Comment: Não deu certo...o erro que ocorre é o mesmo "Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'txtContabilidade' at row 1"...o campo "txtContabilidade" está como LONGTEXT com a collation "latin1_general_ci", aceitando NULL...a query é de update: "update requisicao set txtContabilidade = 'mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm'

Comment: Vi que ele aceita até 200 caracteres somente...

Comment: Tem como enviar a estrutura dessa tabela para que eu simule aqui no meu ambiente?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `requisicao` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txtContabilidade` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: max_allowed_packet = 1048576000

Comment: Resolvido! Depois que fiz as alterações no max_allowed_packet, funcionou!